# Can I generate code coverage from deployments on azure?

Tags: azure, integration-testing, code-coverage, dotcover

We would like to be able to deploy our code to azure and then run integration/acceptance tests on the deployed instances to validate the functionality, as using the emulator does not always give realistic results.

We would also like to have these tests generate code coverage reports which we could then merge in with the code coverage from our unit tests.  We are using TeamCity as our build server with the built in dotcover as our code coverage tool.

Can we do this?  Does anyone have any pointers on where to start?

Comment: There's a video on Channel9 of BUILD 2012 which introduced the continuous integration with Windows Azure Websites. In the video they said we can use .deployment file to build our own build strategy. Not sure if this helps. Here is the video http://channel9.msdn.com/Events/Build/2012/4-002

Comment: If you're looking to do unit testing via azure deployments this may help. (http://deliriousdev.blogspot.ca/?m=1) as for dotcover, I am currently looking into this myself and hope to have a guide up soon and will let you know. I know this is a bit of a late response and if you figured it out already I would be curious to know this as well.

Comment: "Deploy" in what way?  MSI in a VM?  web site? web role?

Comment: @peterritchie Web and worker roles

Answer (score 0):

Check out this video

Kudu can be extended to run Unit Tests and much more more using Custom Deployment Scripts.

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/documentation/videos/custom-web-site-deployment-scripts-with-kudu/